# Problems getting my links to wrap using CSS

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDydm/

Here is what I'm trying to do..

```
div {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width:400px;  
}
.wrap {

}
.longtext{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```
<div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="longtext">This is a bunch of text</span></td>
            <td class="wrap"><a href="">Link1</a><a href="">Link2</a><a href="">Link3</a><a href="">Link4</a><a href="">Link5</a><a href="">Link6</a><a href="">Link7</a><a href="">Link8</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want the long text to not wrap.. but the links to wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually *have* any white space in your links, so they won't wrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDydm/10/

```
<div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="longtext">This is a bunch of text</span></td>
            <td class="wrap">
                <a href="">Link1</a>
                <a href="">Link2</a>
                <a href="">Link3</a>
                <a href="">Link4</a>
                <a href="">Link5</a>
                <a href="">Link6</a>
                <a href="">Link7</a>
                <a href="">Link8</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.wrap a:after { 
    content: " ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDydm/9/

Comment: +1 I like this idea, but unfortunately it's a band-aid on a separate problem (having separate link text all jammed together as one).

Comment: Why add the space with CSS that isn't fully supported when it would be semantically correct to put a space between the links?